# ASP.NET Core start listener when application starts

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I'm working with an Azure service bus queue and wanted to create a listener in my application to listen for and new items added to the queue and then store them locally/send notification.

I need the listener to start with the application and run with the application life cycle.

Having followed the tutorial from Microsoft, I have created two console applications which work just fine. I have then adapted the receiver into an interface, starting the listener within the constructor.

How is the below best linked to the application startup so it permanently listens for new messages in my queue.

My interface is below:

```
namespace PH.Services.AzureServiceBusQueue
{
    public interface IAzureServiceBusQueueClient
    {
    }

    public class AzureServiceBusQueueClient : IAzureServiceBusQueueClient
    {
        // Connection String for the namespace can be obtained from the Azure portal under the 
        // 'Shared Access policies' section.
        const string ServiceBusConnectionString = "connection string";
        const string QueueName = "QueueName";
        static IQueueClient queueClient;
        private readonly CloudStorageSettings _settings;

        public AzureServiceBusQueueClient()
        {
            //_settings = settings;
        ConfigureClient();
    }

    private void ConfigureClient()
    {
        queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);

        // Register QueueClient's MessageHandler and receive messages in a loop
        RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages();

        queueClient.CloseAsync();
    }

    static void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
    {
        // Configure the MessageHandler Options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver etc.
        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            // Maximum number of Concurrent calls to the callback `ProcessMessagesAsync`, set to 1 for simplicity.
            // Set it according to how many messages the application wants to process in parallel.
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,

            // Indicates whether MessagePump should automatically complete the messages after returning from User Callback.
            // False below indicates the Complete will be handled by the User Callback as in `ProcessMessagesAsync` below.
            AutoComplete = false
        };

        // Register the function that will process messages
        queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    }

    static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Process the message
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
        // This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

        // Note: Use the cancellationToken passed as necessary to determine if the queueClient has already been closed.
        // If queueClient has already been Closed, you may chose to not call CompleteAsync() or AbandonAsync() etc. calls 
        // to avoid unnecessary exceptions.
    }

    static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Message handler encountered an exception {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
        var context = exceptionReceivedEventArgs.ExceptionReceivedContext;
        Console.WriteLine("Exception context for troubleshooting:");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Endpoint: {context.Endpoint}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Entity Path: {context.EntityPath}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Executing Action: {context.Action}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a WorkerService for something similar with Azure Event Hubs. Works great for my case (the service is running in a Docker container on AKS then) https://wakeupandcode.com/worker-service-in-asp-net-core/